# Which one of these fallout-shelter questions is a dupe?

Tags: discussion

1 of them is asked with 3 days of the other, but the question intent is still the same.  The answers differ though, and the oldest doesn't have an accepted answer.

Which is the dupe of the other?

- [Do I need a dweller in the storage room?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224447/do-i-need-a-dweller-in-the-storage-room)

  - Asked Jun 20, 2015
  - +4 Q score
  - 3 As, 1 A deleted
  - +7 top A score, not accepted
- [Should I assign dwellers to the storage room?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224914/should-i-assign-dwellers-to-the-warehouse)

  - Asked Jun 23, 2015
  - +9 Q score
  - 2 As, 2 As deleted
  - +3 top A score, accepted

In the game Fallout Shelter, the "Warehouse" is the Storage Room, so it's the same thing, just a different moniker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Do I need a dweller in the storage room?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224447/do-i-need-a-dweller-in-the-storage-room) was closed as a dupe of [Should I assign dwellers to the storage room?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224914/should-i-assign-dwellers-to-the-warehouse), which I assume is due to the high answer quality of the latter question.

Thanks Strix!

Comment: Strix should have answered why she/he closed the question to help us...

Comment: Then page him :)

Answer (score 0):

The two are definetly the same question, given that both users are asking about the same room.

I have seen this come up before, on meta, including a case where a user has asked "why is this a dupe if it was asked first", and from what I see, the accepted action is to mark the question with the least votes as the duplicate.

In this case, the first question has the least votes, but also more answers. **From my currently limited ability to cross reference them** I can see that the highest-voted answer does not actually add anything of value to other answers, that were posted earlier.

The second question, itself, has more upvotes. It has fewer answers, but not only does it have an accepted answer, but the answers do not appear to lack any new information from the first.

I would be flagging the first as a duplicate of the second, given that the question, itself, has less upvotes. The lack of an accepted answer adds weight to this.

Comment: It actually doesn't have much to do with votes, although they are likely circumstantially related. It's mostly a subjective process, but the *better* question with *better* answers should be the canonical one, and the other should be closed as a dupe of it.

Comment: I do think votes are a representation of a better question/answer. Otherwise i am saying "this is better quality because I say so", not "this is better quality because more people in the community think it is good quality"

Comment: @timelord64, votes are *one* such representation, but they can be heavily influenced by a variety of other factors. Of course, that's why 3k+ users and moderators are empowered to make subjective calls as needed.

Comment: @Timelord64 - Votes are also a factor of views and time. An older question might have more views and subsequently more votes, despite being a poorer question.